# Polymer won't render on IIS server

Tags: visual-studio, iis, npm, polymer, visual-studio-2015

I made an empty project in vs 2015 with a basic component, but can't get it to work using IIS, I always get a blank page.
I am NOT using bower since I don't like it . I used vs's NPM to import all the files.
So, here is my setup in an image.

[image: Screenshot]

in my IIS I just right clicked the folder and set -> Convert to application, used the default integrated app pool as usual, and in the project I set it to use my IIS. The links works fine, if I type some text in the body it works.
What could be wrong?

Comment: Any reason why you are using an older version of Polymer (0.5)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have issues with your structure. Most elements try to load Polymer in a link tag at the top of the component definition file ( tag-name.html) . Polymer expects every component to be within its own directory, as well as having the same parent. That being said, you could alter every file to look in the right location after downloading them all, or place all components, and the polymer library itself, into their own folders. A brief example:

```
App/
  Scripts/
     Polymer/
     CustomComponent/
     paper-material/   <-- downloaded paper component
```

This should allow you to not get 404s and multiple downloads of identical files.

The next issue is that you are using the Polymer 1.0 library but implementing it in the 0.5 API. Translating your element to 1.0 (including the conversion of elements into folders) would result in the following:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="ad-nav" noscript>
    <template>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    <template>
</dom-module>
```

This should straighten everything out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you clicked "Convert to Application" in IIS. For regular HTML and JavaScript you do not need to click that option. Don't do that and it will work. Clicking "Convert to Application" in IIS assumes you want a .Net Application, not a plain JavaScript and HTML application.  This changes file and folder permissions which caused your issue.